# Android: Como usar ImageButton?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, botón, app

Soy algo nuevo en esto de Android Studio, y ahora quiero poner un Image Button pero al momento de codificarlo mi App se crashea cuando intento compilar en mi celular. ¿Alguna ayuda?

**XML:**

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/telefono_nine"
        android:layout_width="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/alarmaizq"
        android:layout_below="@+id/alarmaizq"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="50dp"
        android:maxWidth="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/phone"
        android:onClick="telefono_nine"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/phone" />
```

**Codigo:**

```
ImageButton emergencia_nueve = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.telefono_nine);
        emergencia_nueve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                String number="911";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(number));
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Use la propiedad `background` en su lugar de  `src`: `android:background="@drawable/phone"` , haga la prueba y me dice que tal le va.

Comment: Aún me sigue crasheando la app. Sin embargo, la imagen que tenía como botón no mostraba en la pantalla, y al cambiar esa línea de código ya ha aparecido la imagen que quería. Gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que este ejemplo puede servirle de ayuda:

**Crear [ImageButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton) como:**

**XML:**

**Código:**

```
ImageButton ib=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ib);
ib.setOnClickListener(ibLis);
    }
    private OnClickListener ibLis=new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //INICIE SU ACTIVIDAD AQUÍ 
             Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_CURRENT_ACTIVITY.this,NextActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent, 0);
        }
    };
```

---

**Segunda Opción:**

Si desea crear una imagen como botón usando la Vista de botones y luego crear un botón personalizado:

Primero coloque todas sus imágenes como presionadas, enfocadas y predeterminadas en la carpeta `res/drawable` y luego agregue un `newbtn.xml` en `drawable/newbtn.xml` algo como esto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <item android:state_pressed="true"  
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- presionado -->  
    <item android:state_focused="true"  
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- centrado -->  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- Por Defecto -->  
</selector>
```

Finalmente el botón XML establecido `android:background` así:

```
<Button    
    android:id ="@+id/btn"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:text="Hello"  
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"  
    android:background="@drawable/newbtn"   <-- obtener el fondo del botón selector -->
    />
```

Consulte este tutorial para crear un botón personalizado con imágenes

[Creación de botones personalizados y elegantes en Android](http://www.thesecretpie.com/2010/07/creating-custom-fancy-buttons-in.html)

> Fuente SO: [How to create image button in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11176758/8933039)

---

También como apunta la referencia citada arriba puede hacerlo con el elemento `ImageView`, igual con el `onclick`.

**XML:**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/myPic" 
    />
```

**Código:**

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, MyOtherActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

> - [Difference between a clickable ImageView and ImageButton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5847136/8933039)

---

Aquí te dejo unos enlaces que te pueden servir:

> - [How to create image button in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8852420/8933039)
> - [How to use ImageButton state_focused?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30395372/8933039)
> - [ImageButton in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3318629/8933039)
> - [Tutorial: Buttons with (niceley) stretched background](http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_buttons_with_niceley_stretched_background-t4369.html)

Espero te sirva, Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias! Solo tengo unas pequeñas dudas sobre el primer código que puso.

ib.setOnClickListener(ibLis); //Que vendría siendo ibLis?
    }//De dónde se abre esta llave?

Disculpe las molestias.

Comment: @DanielMtz` ibLis` es una instancia del método `OnClickListener()`